# gtk3 - logout during g_application_hold()

Tags: signals, daemon, gtk3, logout

My gtk3 application can either run within a GUI or in daemon-mode. In order to realize daemon-mode, I use [g_application_hold()](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-hold).

So far this works great, however as soon as I logout from my session while running the application in daemon mode, my system freezes for 8 seconds, until OS kills it. Like that my clean shutdown procedure is not executed.
That only happens for the daemon, not while in GUI-mode.

Currently I solved the problem by hooking the SIGHUP signal, which can be used to realize a session logout:

```
static void
handle_hangup_signal (int signal)
{
  MyApplication     *application = my_application_get ();
  g_application_release (G_APPLICATION (application));
}
...
signal(SIGHUP, handle_hangup_signal);
```

This fixes my bug. No 8 second delay, my clean-shutdown is executed.

However I wonder if there is a more clean gtk3 solution? Is it fine to use g_application_hold(), or is there some better gtk3 way to launch something in daemon-mode ?

Comment: Gtk makes sense when there's UI, if not then check GLib functions. Try to separate the logic in order to have the UI dissociated .

Comment: @JoséFonte in this case the application (Xfce's Thunar) starts as daemon to speed up further initializations and to handle file transfers even when the last window is closed. It works fine in its gtk2 version, but after migration to gtk3/GApplication/gdbus this side effect started.

Comment: Well, g_application_hold/release behaves a bit like g_object_ref/unref. If using signals (os) then the application must be *unix only, use glib's unix functions: [g_unix_signal_add/add_full](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-UNIX-specific-utilities-and-integration.html). Not sure why UI Freezes though.

Comment: That's a great hint, I will take a try for g_unix_signal_add/add_full. Thanks alot ! ( Just realized that my current signal-handler is called completely async to gtk's own threads, which could cause some trouble )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I know the reason for this strange behavior. It was caused by a direct `gtk_main_quit()`, triggered by the session-manager.

If a `g_application_release(..).` is executed one line before, there is no logout-delay any more.

Actually even a Gtk-CRITICAL got triggered by this `gtk_main_quit()`:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
```

Till now I just did not see the message because the session-manager already closed the owning console.